# how to order divs in mobile view using bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a responsive template using bootstrap 3. i would like the div order in mobile view to be changed according to the following.

I am new to CSS and so my efforts have been minimal. I don't know where to start with this problem.

when resized to mobile, I need to have the MENU div under the Sunday Dinner div followed by 1/2 PRICE, Our Bar, Our Cuisine, Catering and finally Contact.

Can someone help me with this?

here is the address:

http://www.cambusanj.com/new_site/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for someting like this.

Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You first need to read the Bootstrap doc.
But basically what you want to do looks like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur omnis qui repellendus mollitia nulla, dicta cum ad et architecto atque autem asperiores porro fugit voluptas voluptates sunt aperiam similique minus.</p>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur omnis qui repellendus mollitia nulla, dicta cum ad et architecto atque autem asperiores porro fugit voluptas voluptates sunt aperiam similique minus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur omnis qui repellendus mollitia nulla, dicta cum ad et architecto atque autem asperiores porro fugit voluptas voluptates sunt aperiam similique minus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur omnis qui repellendus mollitia nulla, dicta cum ad et architecto atque autem asperiores porro fugit voluptas voluptates sunt aperiam similique minus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur omnis qui repellendus mollitia nulla, dicta cum ad et architecto atque autem asperiores porro fugit voluptas voluptates sunt aperiam similique minus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```